# disable ios 11+ app offloading programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone

iOS 11 introduced the ability to delete an app, while saving your app settings, for conserving space on a user's device. I want to disable this setting via code for an app I'm creating because it is a high priority (emergency) app. The user will likely not use it for months, but will only need it when there they need it.

Is there a way to disable app offloading programmatically for an individual app or query the devices ability offload setting?  I've not been able to find any documentation for disabling it with a config setting.

Comment: No this is not possible. The "offloading" is done when an app is not used anymore bij the user and when the device is storage is running full.

Comment: the point of _offloading_ is when the user has not been using the app for a while – it will be deleted – so, your users probably have been ignoring your app for a long time before it will be removed, that definitely does not sounds like a _'high priority app what needs to be ready to use all times'_; but I like your confidence.

Comment: @holex The app is a security app, so they will likely not need to use it often.  I have a couple of work arounds in mind given the affirmation of the limitation of being able to disable it per app. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This is a huge problem, especially for B2B apps. App offloading with the B2B app store is broken, because users cannot reinstall their app later.

Comment: @lyndonhughey Did you find any solution for preventing the app from being offloaded. Will sending push notifications to the app prevent it from being offloaded?

Comment: @PersianBlue I did not find a solution. My "solution" does involve marketing attempts sent via push notifications to get the user to open the app. There really should be a permission like "NSOverrideOurAppOffloadingBecauseThisAppCouldSaveYourLife". :)

Comment: I am sure there must be a solution because there are apps I haven’t used for over 3 years and have not been offloaded!